shopify Templates web How do I register a sever worker
shopify root directory register sever worker to achieve webpush system push, what should I do
I tried to register severworker in asset file, but failed to cover all liquid file, unable to use webpush, using webpush from engagelab website, This is the website link https://www.engagelab.com/ who can better way let me operation, thank you
